# Make an address on submit hidden

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form name='myform' method='POST' action='wrapper.php' onsubmit='return valid()'>
```

On submit, it will go to `wrapper.php`. But I want to hide the address `wrapper.php` from the address bar. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: You want to hide what? the address? the content? the link? Please, be more explicit in the approach.

Comment: where don't you want it to show? in the url bar? in your html?

Comment: That is NOT possible. You have to declare the action attribute for a form. If your intention is to ward of hackers, I suggest just strengthening your PHP form processing code security.

Comment: there are a couple good solutions below for you to choose from, both will do what you want, but will is right, neither are bullet proof from hackers

Answer (score 0):

You can have wrapper.php forward to another page once it's done, that will hide it from the url bar, the user can always do a view source or inspect and view the action of your form.  You can obfuscate it and make it **harder** for the user to find via javascript, but you can't absolutely hide where the form posts to from the user

Answer (score 0):

In this form, give your submit button a unique name like say 'myformsubmit'

Remove the action from the form

`<form name='myform' method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' onsubmit='return valid()'>`

On the very top of the page you are having this form, add this.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['myformsubmit'])
{
    require_once 'wrapper.php';
}

?>
```

Comment: interesting solution, it's not bulletproof, but it's definitely creative